# Java File I/O: What condition should i put to stop duplicate writing of letter frequency in a text file?

Tags: java, file-io, character

So I am getting close to finishing my code for character frequency in java. So the directions are to get a text file and save the character frequencies (From A-Z,a-z and 0-9) into another text file, but the number of frequencies are sorted there. Here's what I came up with:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Machine_Exer6 {

public void charfrequency() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File infile = null;
    File result = null;
    Scanner myscan = null;
    JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
    
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    infile = fc.getSelectedFile();
    
    fc.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
    
    fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    result = fc.getSelectedFile();
    
    try {
        myscan = new Scanner(infile);
        while(myscan.hasNextLine()){
            String str = myscan.nextLine();
            Alphanumeric(str, result);
        }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        myscan.close();
    }
    
    
    
}

private void Alphanumeric(String str, File result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    

    int ctr=0;
    PrintWriter printtofile = null;
    try {
        printtofile = new PrintWriter(result);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try{
        for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
            for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
                if((str.charAt(j)==str.charAt(i) || str.charAt(j)==Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) && (Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(j)) || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(j)))){
                    ctr++;
                }
                
            }
            
            if (ctr!=0){
                printtofile.println(str.charAt(j)+": "+ctr);
                ctr=0;
            }
            
        }
    }finally{
        printtofile.close();
    }
    
}
```

But then as I try to read a text file, say, that has its contents as:

> "Whenever
>
> Wherever wherever wherever
>
> you are
>
> i will love, love, love."

The created text file goes like this:

> i: 2
>
> w: 1
>
> i: 2
>
> l: 5
>
> l: 5
>
> l: 5
>
> o: 3
>
> v: 3
>
> e: 3
>
> l: 5
>
> o: 3
>
> v: 3
>
> e: 3
>
> l: 5
>
> o: 3
>
> v: 3
>
> e: 3

also, the uppercase letters aren't included in the lowercase counter. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you create a `Map<Character, Long>` which is the count of each character and only print it once you have the result.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Frequency {

    private static final int DIGIT_START = 48;
    private static final int DIGIT_END   = 57;
    private static final int UPPER_START = 65;
    private static final int UPPER_END   = 90;
    private static final int LOWER_START = 97;
    private static final int LOWER_END   = 122;

    private final BufferedReader reader;
    private final Map<Character, Integer> frequencyCounter;

    public Frequency(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        frequencyCounter = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void calculateFrequency() throws IOException {

        int input;

        while((input = reader.read()) != -1){
            if(isAlphaNeumeric(input)){
                char validInput = (char)Character.toLowerCase(input);
                if(!frequencyCounter.containsKey(validInput)){
                    frequencyCounter.put(validInput, 1);
                }
                else{
                    frequencyCounter.put(validInput,
                       frequencyCounter.get(validInput) + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isAlphaNeumeric(int toTest){

        return isAlphaNewNeumericHelp(toTest, DIGIT_START, DIGIT_END) ||
                isAlphaNewNeumericHelp(toTest, UPPER_START, UPPER_END) ||
                isAlphaNewNeumericHelp(toTest, LOWER_START, LOWER_END);
    }

    private boolean isAlphaNewNeumericHelp(int toTest, 
                                           int lowerBound,          
                                           int upperBound){

        return toTest >= lowerBound && toTest <= upperBound;
    }

    public void printFrequency(){

        final List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> stringCounts = 
            new ArrayList<>(frequencyCounter.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(stringCounts, 
            (o1, o2) -> o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()));

        stringCounts.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Frequency frequency = new Frequency(new File("file"));
        frequency.calculateFrequency();
        frequency.printFrequency();
    }
}
```

The `Map` keeps track of all of the counts. After determining that a character is valid then force it to lower case and cast it to a `char`. If the `Map` does not have an entry that corresponds to the valid character then add one, otherwise update the `Map` value side. For now just print the sorted results to the console.

Hope it helps.